# Scala - Writing Json object to file and reading it

Tags: json, scala, parsing

I have a Map like below

```
val map : scala.collection.mutable.Map[String,Any] = Map(
  dummy1 -> ["cat1", "hash1", 101, 1373269076, {"1" : ["dummy", "dummy", "dummy"]}],
  dummy2 -> ["cat1", "hash1", 102, 1373269076, {"2" : ["dummy", "dummy", "dummy"]}],
  dummy3 -> ["cat1", "hash1", 103, 1373269076, {"3" : ["dummy", "dummy", "dummy"]}]
)
```

I converted it into a Json string and then wrote it into a file with the code below

```
Some(new PrintWriter("foo.txt")).foreach{p =>
  p.write(JSONObject(map.toMap).toString()); p.close
}
```

Am able to read the Json string from the file using

```
val json_string = scala.io.Source.fromFile("foo.txt").getLines.mkString
```

How do I get my map back from the Json string above?

**EDIT:**  Am able to read the map with

```
val map1 = JSON.parseFull(json_string).get.asInstanceOf[Map[String,Any]]
```

But, this process is taking more time as the size of the map increases.

Comment: By `more time`, do you mean O(n) or something worse?  If worse, consider expanding your heap.

Comment: The [ujson](https://github.com/lihaoyi/upickle) library is the best modern solution.  The library in the accepted answer has been archived and isn't active anymore.  See my answer for more details.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try using a likely faster (and more thorough) mapper.

I would recommend using [JacksMapper](https://github.com/wg/jacks) which wraps the excellent [Jackson](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonHome) for a more pleasant Scala usage.

Serializing to JSON becomes as simple as

```
val json = JacksMapper.writeValueAsString[MyClass](instance)
```

... and deserializing

```
val obj = JacksMapper.readValue[MyClass](json)
```

(edit)

You can make also writing and reading simple one-liners using [FileUtils from commons-io](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/apidocs/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html) doing

```
val json = FileUtils readFileToString (file, encoding)
```

and

```
FileUtils write (file, json, encoding)
```

Comment: which Scala version does it support?

Comment: From the first page `This version of jacks has been tested against Scala 2.9.3, 2.10.2 and
  Jackson 2.2.2`

Comment: Am using Scala 2.9.3-RC2. Am getting the error 
jacks_2.10-2.2.2.jar is cross-compiled with an incompatible version of Scala (2.10) immediately after adding the jar file to the project.

Comment: I am using it with 2.10.2. Did you get the correct one ? Accoridng to my maven repo the 2.9.3 version is `<dependency>
  <groupId>com.lambdaworks</groupId>
  <artifactId>jacks_2.9.3</artifactId>
  <version>2.2.0</version>
</dependency>`

Comment: I did the same. There are no errors in the code. But, eclipse is showing 2 problems 1) Error in Scala compiler, 2) SBT builder crashed while compiling. Do I need to add Jackson jar too?

Comment: yes. This is just a wrapper around Jackson. Jackson-databind 2.2.2 should do.

Comment: to be thorough (in case you do not use Maven and pull dependencies automagically), you need jackson-core, jackson-databind and jackson-annotations

Answer (score 5):

I actually got a lot more use from [json4s](https://github.com/json4s/json4s/blob/3.4/tests/src/test/scala/org/json4s/ExtractionExamplesSpec.scala). The documentation is much more clear and comprehensive, and the usage seems slightly easier.

A similar operation to the one you are requesting would look like this

```
import org.json4s.native.JsonFormats.parse

... get your json string ...
val parsedJson = parse(json)
val extractedJson = parsedJson.extract[MyClass]
```

Answer (score 3):

[ujson](https://github.com/lihaoyi/upickle) is the best modern solution to read and write JSON.

Here's how to build up an object and write it to disk:

```scala
val weirdData = ujson.Obj(
  "something1" -> ujson.Arr("cat1", "hash1", 101),
  "something2" -> ujson.Arr("cat2", "hash2", 102),
  "something3" -> ujson.Arr("cat3", "hash3", 103)
)
os.write(os.pwd/"tmp"/"weird_data.json", weirdData)
```

Here are the contents of the `weird_data.json` file:

```
{
  "something1":["cat1","hash1",101],
  "something2":["cat2","hash2",102],
  "something3":["cat3","hash3",103]
}
```

You can easily read this data from a JSON file to a ujson object.

```scala
val jsonString = os.read(os.pwd/"tmp"/"weird_data.json")
val data = ujson.read(jsonString)
// here's what data contains
ujson.Value.Value = Obj(
  LinkedHashMap(
    "something1" -> Arr(ArrayBuffer(Str("cat1"), Str("hash1"), Num(101.0))),
    "something2" -> Arr(ArrayBuffer(Str("cat2"), Str("hash2"), Num(102.0))),
    "something3" -> Arr(ArrayBuffer(Str("cat3"), Str("hash3"), Num(103.0)))
  )
)
```

Here's how to grab a value from the ujson object.

```scala
data("something2")(1).str // "hash2"
```

See [here](https://mungingdata.com/scala/read-write-json/) for more details on writing JSON data with Scala.