# Scala Convert a string into a map

Tags: json, scala, dictionary

What is the fastest way to convert this

`{"a":"ab","b":"cd","c":"cd","d":"de","e":"ef","f":"fg"}`

into mutable map in scala ? I read this input string from ~500MB file. That is the reason I'm concerned about speed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That looks like a JSON file, as Andrey says. You should [consider this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17521364/scala-writing-json-object-to-file-and-reading-it). It gives some example Scala code. Also, this answer gives some [different JSON libraries and their relative merits](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8054018/json-library-for-scala).

Answer (score 15):

If your JSON is as simple as in your example, i.e. a sequence of key/value pairs, where each value is a string. You can do in plain Scala :

```
myString.substring(1, myString.length - 1)
        .split(",")
        .map(_.split(":"))
        .map { case Array(k, v) => (k.substring(1, k.length-1), v.substring(1, v.length-1))}
        .toMap
```

Answer (score 2):

The fastest way to read tree data structures in XML or JSON is by applying streaming API: [Jackson Streaming API To Read And Write JSON](http://www.mkyong.com/java/jackson-streaming-api-to-read-and-write-json/).

Streaming would split your input into tokens like 'beginning of an object' or 'beginning of an array' and you would need to build a parser for these token, which in some cases is not a trivial task.

Answer (score -1):

Keeping it simple.  If reading a json string from file and converting to scala map

```
import spray.json._
import DefaultJsonProtocol._

val jsonStr = Source.fromFile(jsonFilePath).mkString
val jsonDoc=jsonStr.parseJson
val map_doc=jsonDoc.convertTo[Map[String, JsValue]]

// Get a Map key value
val key_value=map_doc.get("key").get.convertTo[String]

// If nested json, re-map it.
val key_map=map_doc.get("nested_key").get.convertTo[Map[String, JsValue]]
println("Nested Value " + key_map.get("key").get)
```