# Converting a String to a Map

Tags: scala

Given a String : `{'Name':'Bond','Job':'Agent','LastEntry':'15/10/2015 13:00'}`

I want to parse it into a `Map[String,String]`, I already tried [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19942037/5445792) but it doesn't work when the character `:` is inside the parsed value. Same thing with the `'` character, it seems to break every JSON Mappers...

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let

```
val s0 = "{'Name':'Bond','Job':'Agent','LastEntry':'15/10/2015 13:00'}"
val s = s0.stripPrefix("{").stripSuffix("}")
```

Then

```
(for (e <- s.split(",") ; xs = e.split(":",2)) yield xs(0) -> xs(1)).toMap
```

Here we split each key-value by the first occurrence of `":"`. Further this is a strong assumption, in that the key does not contain any `":"`.

Comment: And you should take care of { }

Answer (score 2):

You can use the familiar [jackson-module-scala](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-module-scala) that can do this in much better scale.

For example:

```
val src = "{'Name':'Bond','Job':'Agent','LastEntry':'15/10/2015 13:00'}"
val mapper = new ObjectMapper() with ScalaObjectMapper
mapper.registerModule(DefaultScalaModule)
val myMap = mapper.readValue[Map[String,String]](src)
```